# Get data from PHP query using JSON not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, mysqli

my php code is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='admin' AND password='MTIz'";
$result = $link->query($query);
$yes = array();
$yes[] = $result->num_rows;
echo json_encode($yes);
```

And my HTML code is:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'vlogin.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: myData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(yes) {
    alert(yes.Result);}
});
```

Not return anything. What appens?  Thanks

Comment: what does alert show?can you try removing `contentType`

Comment: Try `$yes['Result'] = $result->num_rows;`

Comment: do a `console.log(yes)` to see exactly what's inside your response

Comment: Can you post your JSON code? Make sure it's valid.

Comment: What kind of Object is `$link` ?
What is `$result->num_rows` supposed to contain? Is it an object? Is it an integer?
Where do you define the `Result` index?
When writing `$yes = array();
$yes[] = $result->num_rows;`
you won't have any `$yes['Result']` but a `$yes[0]['Result']`

Comment: Can you show `$yes` array by printing it. show us what records you are getting?

Comment: Check in console the return json response

Answer (score 1):

When using $.ajax(), I usually implement the error callback :

From the jquery doc : 
[error](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ))

Implementing it allows you to see if the call is generating (bad JSON) or receiving (webservice error) errors : you can log/alert textStatus and errorThrown.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'vlogin.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: myData,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(yes) {
          console.log(yes.Result);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(textStatus);
          console.log(errorThrown);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='admin' AND       password='MTIz'";
$result = $link->query($query);
$yes = array();
$yes[] = $result->num_rows;
echo json_encode($yes);
die;
```

apply die after the `json_encode($yes);` it will give you result then

and alert only yes like this `alert(yes);`

Comment: Could you also please explain how does that `die;` help?

Comment: Because some times more code is ran before being sent to the next page.

Comment: sometimes without `die;` the function after encoding direct to any other controller. i faced the same problem when i applied `die;`, the issue was resolved. not sure it will work for you guyz or not! but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='admin' AND password='MTIz'";
 $result = $link->query($query);
 $yes = array();
 $yes['record'] = $result->num_rows;
 echo json_encode($yes);
```

And  `.ajax`

```
  $.ajax({
          url: 'vlogin.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: myData,
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(yes) {
          console.log(yes.record);
    }
 });
```